# if we fetch the data from database scroll down is not working using javascript and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Without fetching data from database, if we insert message scroll is getting down properly. But if we fetch the data from database scroll down is not working.

Insert and fetching data from database form

```
 <div class="panel-body msg_container_base">
                                <?php foreach ($customer_to_supplier as $row ) { ?>


                                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent" >
                                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                            <div class="messages msg_sent">
                                                <p ><?php echo $row->message; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div class="row msg_container base_receive">
                                    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                                        <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                            <p><?php // echo $row->message; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <chat_log> . </chat_log>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>




     <form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom"   method="POST" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication"> 
                                            <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
                                                <div class="input-group submit_group">
         *
        <!--                                        <input type ="hidden" name="suppid" id="suppid" value="<?php // echo $row->supplier_id;  ?>" class="form-control" />
                                                <input type ="hidden" name="proid" id="proid" value="<?php // echo $row->product_id;  ?>" class="form-control" />
                                                <input type ="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" value="<?php // echo $row->Customer_id;  ?>" class="form-control" />-->



                                                    <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />


                                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

script

```
       <script>
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                var data = $("#messagee").val();
                //console.log(data);
                $('chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent"><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p>' + .message + '</p></div></div></div>');
                clearInput();
                console.log($('.msg_container_base').innerHeight())
                $('.msg_container_base').scrollTop($('.msg_container_base')[0].scrollHeight)
            });

//            function clearInput() {
//                $("#myForm :input").each(function () {
//                    $(this).val(''); //hide form values
//                });
//            }
//
//            $("#myForm").submit(function () {
//                return false; //to prevent redirection to save.php
//            });

        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll down"? your question is not clear. did u mean html body scroll??

Comment: I think you want infinite scrolling feature in your app, isn't it?

Comment: s/jacascript/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my below code

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
                scrollDown();
                $("#submit").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var message = $("#messagee").val();
                    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent active"><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div></div>');
                    $('#messagee').val('');
                    scrollDown();
                });
            });


            function scrollDown() {
                $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
            }
```

```css
 .text-danger {
                color: #ff0500;
                font-size: 10px;
                float: right;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            /*newmessage css*/
            .msg_container_base{
                background: #e5e5e5;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 10px 10px;
                max-height:80vh;
                overflow-x:hidden;
            }
            .top-bar {
                background: #666;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px;
                position: relative;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .msg_receive{
                padding-left:0;
                margin-left:0;
            }
            .msg_sent{
                padding-bottom:20px !important;
                margin-right:0;
            }
            .messages {
                background: white;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                max-width:100%;
            }
            .messages > p {
                font-size: 13px;
                margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
            }
            .messages > time {
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #ccc;
            }
            .msg_container {
                padding: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }


            .base_receive > .avatar:after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border: 5px solid #FFF;
                border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }

            .base_sent {
                justify-content: flex-end;
                align-items: flex-end;
            }
            .base_sent > .avatar:after {
                content: "";
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                border: 5px solid white;
                border-right-color: transparent;
                border-top-color: transparent;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.2); 
            }

            .msg_sent > time{
                float: right;
            }



            .msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar-track
            {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                background-color: #F5F5F5;
            }

            .msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar
            {
                width: 12px;
                background-color: #F5F5F5;
            }

            .msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
            {
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                background-color: #555;
            }

            .btn-group.dropup{
                position:relative;
                left:0px;
                bottom:0;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="panel-body msg_container_base">
            <div class="row msg_container base_sent" >
                <div id="chat_log"> 
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form"   method="POST" role="form"> 
            <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
                <div class="input-group submit_group">



                    <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />


                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Let me know if it not works .

Comment: by using this script scrolling function is working but data is not inserting into database,if we comment e.preventDefault();  data is inserted into database.

Comment: Actually I have given you solution for Ajax chat method

Comment: If you want to submit form than cut this line `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#endhere').position().top}, 'slow');` and put before `$("#submit").click(function (e) {` this line

Comment: Scrolling is not getting down completely we need to scroll to see new message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146938/discussion-between-p-prasanthi-and-shyam-shingadiya).

Comment: Please check my updated snippet, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: So what is the issue in this..?

Comment: Actually, i am having messages down in order to see those current messages i need to scroll down when exactly message has sent.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Please check my updated answer, finally its working as you expected.

Comment: @PPrasanthi : Glad to help out from this hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

I also occured with the same problem and i resolved it because my header position is fixed then after changing to relative it worked try to change position to relative rather than fixed

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference